# Only English Option when Importing a Language File

Tags: multilingual

Does anyone know why when importing a language file I am only given the option to choose english. Every two weeks I work with our translations provider and send them english items that are needed for translation and normally when I import them back in, I get the option of English and Spanish, for which I only select Spanish so I don't accidentally update English items that have been updated since they went out for translation.

The last batch, when I import is only giving me the English option when importing. I have viewed the xml file and both  and  nodes exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the file itself? My guess is that it only contains language tags for English.

Comment: Yes and both <en> and <es> nodes are there and populated. We are starting the next round of translations this week so I will see if it happens two times in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response back from Sitecore Support. The VM I was using to import the file did not have the es-ES culture present. After using a VM that did, the Spanish checkbox was present.

From Support:

> Please make sure that es-ES culture is present on your machine. Please
>   also check whether the issue is reproduced after replacing all the
>    tags with  in your translation files.